# How can i change the format of the raffles

Tags: python, random, sqlalchemy

Hi im having trouble chaning the format of the generated raffles as it appears it stands like this  Aqua   49250097 and what im trying to achive is something like this Aqua 4925 0097  and im not getting any raffle beging with 0 for example like blue 0223 4773.
heres my code

```
from sqlalchemy import *
import random

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///raffle.db')

metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

raffles_table = Table('raffles', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('email', String(40)),
        Column('raffle_color', String(40)),
        Column('raffle_ticket', Integer),
        )

# create tables in database
metadata.create_all(checkfirst=True)

# create a database connection
conn = engine.connect()

def add_raffles():
    email = input("Please enter your email address:")
    num_tickets = int(input("How many tickets do you want:"))

    for i in range(num_tickets):
        ins_raffle = raffles_table.insert()
        colors = ['blue','Pink','Plum','Aqua','Navy','Grey','Rose','Ruby','Teal','Gold','Jade','Lime']
        color = random.choice(colors)
        ticket = random.randrange(10 ** 8)
        new_raffle = ins_raffle.values(email = email, raffle_color = color, raffle_ticket = ticket)
        # add raffle to database by executing SQL
        conn.execute(new_raffle)
        print(color + "   " + str(ticket))

def select_winner():
    winner_query = raffles_table.select().order_by(func.random()).limit(2)
    winner = conn.execute(winner_query)
    for row in winner:
        print("The winner is:" + row['email'])
        print("The winning raffle is:" + row['raffle_color'] +"  " + str(row['raffle_ticket']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `add_raffles()` look like this:

```
def add_raffles():
    email = input("Please enter your email address:")
    num_tickets = int(input("How many tickets do you want:"))

    for i in range(num_tickets):
        ins_raffle = raffles_table.insert()
        colors = ['blue','Pink','Plum','Aqua','Navy','Grey','Rose','Ruby','Teal','Gold','Jade','Lime']
        color = random.choice(colors)
        ticket = random.randrange(10 ** 8)
        new_raffle = ins_raffle.values(email = email, raffle_color = color, raffle_ticket = ticket) 
        # add raffle to database by executing SQL 
        conn.execute(new_raffle)
        ticket_string = str(ticket).zfill(8)
        print(color + "    " + " ".join((ticket_string[:4], ticket_string[-4:])))
```

Notice, at the end, the addition of `ticket_string` and the changed `print` statement.

Comment: where do i repleace      ticket_string = str(ticket).zfill(8)  with

Comment: Put `ticket_string = str(ticket).zfill(8)` right above the `print` statement, and then change your `print` statement to the one I gave.

Comment: im having my synatx erros could u please do the changes on the code please

Comment: im getting systax error  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\osman_000\Documents\My Data Files\add-raffle.py", line 2, in <module>
    raffle.add_raffles()
  File "C:\Users\osman_000\Documents\My Data Files\raffle.py", line 34, in add_raffles
    print(color + "    " + " ".join(ticket_string[:4], ticket_string[-4:]))
TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: Sorry, you need to put extra parentheses around the `join` method so that the arguments are in a tuple.  I edited my answer to show it.

Comment: like this  print(color + "    " + " ".(join)(ticket_string[:4], ticket_string[-4:]))

Comment: No, like this: `print(color + " " + " ".join((ticket_string[:4], ticket_string[-4:])))`

Answer (score 1):

You are repeatedly defining `colors` for no reason. Move it to the top of your script and make it a constant, ie

```
COLORS = "Blue Pink Plum Aqua Navy Grey Rose Ruby Teal Gold Jade Lime".split()
```

You are generating tickets independently; it is unlikely but possible to generate the same value twice, and the odds increase more-than-linearly with the number of tickets. If you generate ten thousand tickets, the probability of having at least one duplicate is about 4%; for twenty thousand tickets, it is about 15%; for a hundred thousand tickets it is over 98%. Depending on your use maybe you don't care, but it is something to keep in mind (how do you feel about being on the hook for two grand prizes?).

Depending on how many tickets one person generally buys, you might be able to save some space by putting emails in a separate table. You could also save quite a bit of space by storing a single integer,

```
BASE = 10 ** 8
NUM_COLORS = len(COLORS)

ticket = random.randrange(NUM_COLORS * BASE)
```

and only splitting it for display, like

```
color_index, rem = divmod(ticket, BASE)
color = COLORS[color_index]
num_a, num_b = divmod(rem, 10 ** 4)
print("Your ticket is: {} {:04d} {:04d}".format(color, num_a, num_b))
```

which gives results like

```
Your ticket is: Lime 2592 1700
Your ticket is: Navy 0828 6111
Your ticket is: Lime 3741 7599
Your ticket is: Ruby 4017 4645
Your ticket is: Aqua 0556 1852
Your ticket is: Grey 2486 5298
Your ticket is: Gold 0195 8990
Your ticket is: Navy 9287 8727
Your ticket is: Blue 3736 3443
Your ticket is: Lime 9365 1980
Your ticket is: Plum 2247 9671
Your ticket is: Lime 6568 5285
Your ticket is: Pink 7591 3894
Your ticket is: Grey 6839 4780
Your ticket is: Pink 9348 9882
Your ticket is: Plum 3868 6449
Your ticket is: Rose 2588 7999
Your ticket is: Grey 0625 5061
Your ticket is: Rose 2132 8136
Your ticket is: Navy 0526 4325
```

Comment: hi thanks again could you embedd this into the code and also when i generate winners it dosent space out in 4s.